# Kubernetes + consul: kv.get: connect ETIMEDOUT

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, consul

I have deployed consul using **hashicorp-consul-helm-chart**
now, I want to connect to the consul from my Node.js project.

Therefore, I created an object like this : (using 'consul' npm package)

```js
import consul from 'consul';

var consulObj = new consul({
  host: 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
  promisify: true
});

var watch = consulObj.watch({
  method: consulObj.kv.get,
  options: { key: 'config' },
  backoffFactor: 1000,
});
```

I have got the host value from `kubectl get endpoints`
used the value opposite to consul-server

[image]

still, i get `consul: kv.get: connect ETIMEDOUT` when I run the code.
what could be the reason?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: stupid question: can you confirm your pods are running? I also assume you mean `kubectl get endpoints`

Comment: i would sugegst you to check the connection using consul agent first. try to connect with side container first docker image : consul:1.2.0 however as Jordan mentioned your PODs are up & running ?

Comment: Also, what are you using as HOST internal SVC IP or SVC name, if using internal SVC name both are in same namespace? Are you running your Node program locally or running on same cluster ?

Comment: Yes I meant kubectl get endpoints, thats just a typo, corrected now @JordanShaw

Comment: Yes, consul pods are up and running, moreover code runs on the same cluster.
The namespace is different ! @HarshManvar

Comment: @KevalBhogayata are you using internal IP or SVC name in host ?

Comment: not using service name, using the IP that I am getting in kubectl get endpoints, not sure if  its called Internal IP

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227935/discussion-between-harsh-manvar-and-keval-bhogayata).

Answer (score 0):

You should be accessing the Consul client which is running on the node where your app is located instead of directly accessing the server.

Details can be found in the accepted answer for [Hashicorp Consul, Agent/Client access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64770593/hashicorp-consul-agent-client-access/64780058#64780058).